# Windows 10 UWP Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, windows-10-iot-core

I recently started developing for Windows UWP, but know I’m stuck at speech recognition.
According to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-recognition.

> Customize the recognition UI
>
> When your app attempts speech recognition by calling
>   SpeechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync, several screens are shown in
>   the following order.
>
> If you're using a constraint based on a predefined grammar (dictation
>   or web search):
>
> - The Listening Screen
> - The Thinking Screen
> - The Heard You Say Screen

This is my code:

```cs
var language = new Windows.Globalization.Language("es-ES");

var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(language);

await recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = 
                                    await recognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, 
                                   "Escuchado:");

await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

I’m using the RecognizeWithUIAsync() due my app being a desktop application, but I don’t want the “Heard you say” screen, because it converts the spoken text to speech using the system TTS, I mean, is tedious. ¿is there a way to keep only the listening and thinking screen?

Comment: So you don't like "WithUI".  Then don't use it and make your own.

Comment: "Then don't use it and make your own"... isn't that what i'm asking?. So you don't like "Answer a way to achieve this". Then don't comment and make yourself silent.

Comment: If you don't want TTS feedback provided by the `RecognizeWithUIAsync` method. Use the `RecognizeAsync` method instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did it and is working, plus, I added some events to mimic the behavior of the "Thinking Screen" using hypothesis handler.